# Blackberry app submit

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

I try to submit app in app world, 
when I try to submit app with this .alx file it says that is not good

what is wrong?

```
<loader version="1.0">
<application id="AppTest">
    <name >
        AppTest
    </name>
    <description >
        AppTest
    </description>
    <version >
        1.5
    </version>
    <vendor >
        Vendor
    </vendor>
    <copyright >
        Copyright (c) 2011 Vendor
    </copyright>
    <fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[5.0.0)">
        <directory >
            5.0.0
        </directory>
        <files >
            AppTest.cod
        </files>
    </fileset>
</application>
```

Comment: when try to submit app without .alx file it says:
Release 1.0 does not specify a English(en) bundle for device (and all devices that I checked in)

Comment: Invalid binary file (AppTest.alx4914959318353883278.alx)
its says

Comment: do not upload .alx files. only upload .cod files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can submit app to the appworld by just submitting the signed .cod file so just try to submit using .cod file.